# Why integrate out the random effect instead of jointly estimating all model parameters?

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, biostatistics

For simplicity, say I have a model with one random effect:
`Y ~ N(XB + Zu, sigma)`, `u ~ N(0, sigma')`
So the likelihood function to optimize would be

`P(Y | X, B, u, sigma) * P(u | sigma')`

Most often, I see `u` integrated out, `sigma'` estimated treating `B` and `sigma` as nuisance parameters, then `B`, `sigma` and `u` are estimated (correct me if Im wrong).

Why not jointly estimate the parameters from the likelihood function above?  With more complex models, these integrals get very complex. Would joint estimation produce the same parameter estimates? Joint estimation would avoid having to do the numerical integration. I have seen related questions but they do not fully address this. The only reason I see for doing this is that u is unobserved, so you integrate it out.  But what difference does it make?

Comment: Someone does exactly what you describe, It’s called hierarchical generalized linear models or HGLM.

Comment: I don't consider $u$ to be a parameter. You can write the model as $Y=Xb + Zu + e$ where $e$ are residuals and $u$ are random effects. We don't consider $u$ to be a fundamental parameter for the same reason that $e$ is not. Sure, we can estimate $e$ or $u$, but that is done by estimating the fundamental parameters $b$, $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ and then computing the expected values of $u$ and $e$ given the data and the parameters.

Comment: Mixed models are a very complex area of statistical theory, with a variety of different approaches. You might like to lookup papers on "BLUPs" (best-linear-unbiased-predictors), which provide a way to estimate $u$ given the fundamental parameters. See for example "That BLUP is a Good Thing: The Estimation of Random Effects" https://www.jstor.org/stable/2245695.

Comment: Would joint estimation vs integrating out u then estimating B, sigma and sigma' produce the same parameter estimates?